# Bugzilla - The Graphical Reports feature is throwing error even after installing the required components

Tags: charts, report, bugzilla

Installed all the required GD Components and while trying to generate graphical report getting the following error message.

Bugzilla has suffered an internal error. Please save this page and send it to bugz_ADMIN@mail.com with details of what you were doing at the time this message appeared.

URL: http://`xxxxxxxxxxxx`/report.cgi?product=xxxxxxxxxxx&resolution=---&x_axis_field=bug_status&y_axis_field=component&width=600&height=350&action=wrap&format=line

The Graphical Reports feature is not available in this Bugzilla. If you would like to enable this feature, please run checksetup.pl to see how to install the necessary requirements for this feature.
    Traceback:at D:/Program Files (x86)/Bugzilla/bugzilla/report.cgi line 101

Output of Checksetup.pl

```
  * This is Bugzilla 4.2.5 on perl 5.10.1
* Running on Win7 Build 7600

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.63
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.48
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.21)     ok: found v2.24
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v0.53
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.79)     ok: found v1.10
Checking for                  DBI (v1.41)     ok: found v1.609
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.22
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.16)     ok: found v2.198
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.911
Checking for                  URI (v1.37)     ok: found v1.52
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.22)     ok: found v0.22
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004
Checking for                Win32 (v0.35)     ok: found v0.39
Checking for            Win32-API (v0.55)     ok: found v0.59
Checking for                 JSON (v2.10)     ok: found v2.17
Checking for            Text-Diff (v0.35)     ok: found v1.37
Checking for           GD-Graph3d (v0.63)     ok: found v0.63

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v1.45)     ok: found v2.16.1
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.012
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     ok: found v1.29
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.44
Checking for                Chart (v2.1)      ok: found v2.4.1
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       ok: found v1.56
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.44
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.427
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v5.834
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.34
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    found v0.9.5
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.39
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.13
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.17
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    found v0.710.10
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       not found
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      ok: found v2.27
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       not found
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.40)     ok: found v3.64
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.08
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.39
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       not found
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)       not found
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       not found
Checking for          TheSchwartz (any)       not found
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found
Checking for             Text-CSV (v1.06)     not found
Checking for XML Schema Validator (v1.10)     not found
Checking for    XML Schema Parser (any)       ok: found v1.01
Checking for             XML Twig (any)       ok: found v3.34
WARNING: We could not check the configuration of Apache. This sometimes
happens when you are not running checksetup.pl as Administrator. To see the
problem we ran into, run: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\apache\bin\httpd.EXE -
t -D DUMP_MODULES

***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*                    MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                 *
***********************************************************************
*                    PatchReader * Patch Viewer                       *
*                      SOAP-Lite * XML-RPC Interface                  *
*                       JSON-RPC * JSON-RPC Interface                 *
*                     Test-Taint * JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface *
*                  Encode-Detect * Automatic charset detection for text attachme
nts *
* Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper * Inbound Email                      *
*                    Email-Reply * Inbound Email                      *
*                    TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                      *
*                 Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                      *
*                       mod_perl * mod_perl                           *
*               Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                           *
*                       Text-CSV * CSV Importing of test cases        *
*           XML Schema Validator * XML Importing of test cases and plans *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

    PatchReader: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl PatchReader
      SOAP-Lite: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl SOAP::Lite
       JSON-RPC: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl JSON::RPC
     Test-Taint: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl Test::Taint
  Encode-Detect: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl Encode::Detect
Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\pe
rl.exe install-module.pl Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper
    Email-Reply: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl Email::Reply
    TheSchwartz: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl Daemon::Generic
       mod_perl: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl mod_perl2
Apache-SizeLimit: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install
-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit
       Text-CSV: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-
module.pl Text::CSV
XML Schema Validator: D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe ins
tall-module.pl XML::Validator::Schema


To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  D:\Program Files (x86)\Bugzilla\perl\perl\bin\perl.exe install-module.pl --all


Reading ./localconfig...
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.012
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.1.44-community-log

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.

Checking Testopia setup ...
Done checking Testopia setup.

checksetup.pl complete.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed GraphViz http://www.graphviz.org/ and configured the webdotbase parameter?